# Can we use Lombok in Embedded Java?

Tags: java, embedded, lombok

Can we use lombok framework in embedded Java? Like midlets or implementations where we need only core java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I expect that you can use lombok in embedded Java.

Lombok is a compile time dependency, and not related to any deployment platform.

You might want to modify `lombok.config` and instruct lombok to not generate `@ConstructorProperties` using `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties=true` (in the upcoming release, this will be the default behavior and deprecated), since I expect that that is not available at runtime.

Also, the generated code is optimized for hotspot, so you might also want to configure `lombok.equalsAndHashCode.doNotUseGetters=true` and `lombok.toString.doNotUseGetters=true` to use direct field access instead of getters.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: Thank you, Roel for the quick response and the details. Do you know of any embedded project that uses  Lombok?